# Scrollable JPanel without scrollBar

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with scroling JPanel,
I have a lot of labels and fields which are generated dynamicly, but my frame can't show it all.

My code:

```
JPanel showPanel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(showPanel);
add(scrollPane);
scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
scrollPane.setVisible(true);
scrollPane.add(Jbuttons);
```

And Im adding a lot of these buttons but my scrollPane won't show it.
I don't have any scrollBar, with text area I didn't have any problems.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. `scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);` looks like you're using a `null` layout, don't this
2. `scrollPane.add(Jbuttons);` isn't how you should be adding content to the scroll pane, instead, add it to the `showPanel` which is already inside the `JScrollPane`.  `JScrollPane` contains a single component, the `JViewport`, you can not "add" components to the `JScrollPane`, you must set the `JViewport`s view to what you want shown and the manipulate this view

[image]

Take a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details